# Pass navigation from child component to parent getting TypeError

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I'm facing an issue whenever i tried to navigate to another screens. I'm using the navigation in  child component and it doesn't work even i passed the props to the parent component. This is my first time on using react navigation. I've tried many possible solution yet still can't solve this issue. I'm using react navigation 5 and i need help. I'm getting an error as such :

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')
```

```
Home.js // Parent Component

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Cards
      title="In Progress"
      imgUri={require('../assets/CardProgress.png')}
      navigateAction={() =>
        this.props.navigation.navigate('SiteAudit')
      }
    )
  }
}
```

```
Card.js // Child Component

const Cards = (props) => {
  return (
    <CardContainer
      backgroundColor={props.backgroundColor}
      onPress={() => {
        props.navigation.navigateAction;
      }}>
      <CardWrapper>
        <CardTitle>{props.title}</CardTitle>
        <CardImage source={props.imgUri} />
      </CardWrapper>
    </CardContainer>
  );
};
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Dashboard from './screens/Dashboard';
import SiteAudit from './screens/SiteAudit';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator();
const DashboardStack = createStackNavigator();
const SiteAuditStack = createStackNavigator();

const DashboardScreen = () => {
  return (
    <DashboardStack.Navigator>
      <DashboardStack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    </DashboardStack.Navigator>
  );
};

const SiteAuditScreen = () => {
  return (
    <SiteAuditStack.Navigator>
      <SiteAuditStack.Screen name="SiteAudit" component={SiteAudit} />
    </SiteAuditStack.Navigator>
  );
};

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Dashboard">
        <RootStack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={DashboardScreen} />
        <RootStack.Screen name="SiteAudit" component={SiteAuditScreen} />
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue, I just need to re-read the documentation of react navigation. I need to use the `useNavigation` that has been stated here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/

```
Cards.js // Child Component

const Cards = (props) => {
  return (
    <CardContainer
      backgroundColor={props.backgroundColor}
      onPress={props.navigationAction}>
      <CardWrapper>
        <CardTitle>{props.title}</CardTitle>
        <CardImage source={props.imgUri} />
      </CardWrapper>
    </CardContainer>
  );
};
```

```
Home.js // Parent Component

import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

const Home = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <Cards
      title="Completed"
      backgroundColor="#0082C8"
      navigationAction={() => {
        navigation.navigate('Site Audit');
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your card view as follows

```
<Cards
      title="In Progress"
      imgUri={require('../assets/CardProgress.png')}
      onPress={() => this.buttonPress()}
/>

const buttonPress = () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Site Audit');
};
```

Edit your button as follows,

```
<TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.cardButton}
      onPress={onPress}
      <Text style={styles.cardTitle}>{this.props.title}</Text>
      <Image style={styles.imageCard} source={this.props.imgUri} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Hi, how can u without knowing assume that he is using class based component and not functional component, as far as i know functional component doesn't have this keyword in existence.

Comment: @AyushiKeshri in functional components we don't want to use prop.navigation.navigate that's why I assumed that in functional components we use navigation.navigate

Comment: Hi @RuchiraSwarnapriya, thank you for the comment however it still doesn't work. Same error. Yes, I'm using class based component. Sorry, I've edited the post.

Comment: I've tried the suggestion solution, same error still occured. I'll try my best to find the solution. Thank you! @RuchiraSwarnapriya

Comment: Hi sir, can you help me again on this problem? I'm still stuck, btw I'm using react navigation 5. I've edited the post.

Comment: @amrxlamn Change your TouchableOpacity as I have done, and write function for navigation like have done, It'll work

Comment: @RuchiraSwarnapriya I get and error TypeError: _this.buttonPress is not a function. (In '_this.buttonPress()', '_this.buttonPress' is undefined) while from eslint state that 'buttonPress' is assigned a value but never used.

Comment: have you add Stack.Screen name correctly ?